# Boost Process fails to launch the firefox browser (ubuntu 14.04, eclipse mars CDT)

Tags: c++, eclipse, firefox, ubuntu, boost

This snippet of code fails to launch the firefox browser. Note I am trying to invoke the Boost.Process on a boost thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>

const std::string BROWSER_EXE = "firefox";

void LaunchStream(std::string url)
{
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    args.push_back(url);

    boost::process::context ctx;
    ctx.stderr_behavior = boost::process::redirect_stream_to_stdout();
    ctx.stdout_behavior = boost::process::silence_stream();

    std::string exe = boost::process::find_executable_in_path(BROWSER_EXE);
    boost::process::child proc = boost::process::launch(exe, args, ctx); <---DOES NOT LAUNCH FIREFOX
    proc.wait();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string url = <some url to open>;

    boost::thread streamThread(LaunchStream, url);

    <wait a long time>
}
```

What I do observe is a zombie firefox process from: ps -ef | grep "firefox"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use the application name "firefox" as 0. and the url as 1. argument `args = {exe, url}`. Also there is a later version of boost process (0.5) with a different api which works much better: http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/

Comment: I did try the newer 0.5 version, and now get a different error. When attempting to launch chrome or firefox I get errors related to an inability to open a graphics display ([8605:8605:1007/081052:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(237)] Gtk: cannot open display: ). Is there a limitation on the Boost.Process library that means graphical apps can't be opened?

Comment: Could you link your new version? /EDIT: by the way did you try to join your thread?